# Run a GUI and play a alarm sound simultaneously in python using easygui and pyaudio

Tags: python, multithreading, pyaudio, easygui

Hi I need to run my gui simultaneously with my alarm sound and stop the iterating alarm sound when i click ok button in the 2nd dialog box. To achieve this task i created 2 files which is the main file(gui using [easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/)) and the AudioFile class witch uses [pyaudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) to play and stop alarm sound.

main file:

```
from easygui import *
import sys
from AudioFile import *

    predictions[0] = 1

a = AudioFile("alarm.wav")

if (predictions[0] == 1):
    while 1:
            #play alarm sound
        a.play()
        msgbox("Critical Situation Detected!")


        msg ="Please choose an action?"
        title = "Critical Situation Detected!"
        choices = ["Ignore the Warning", "Contact Doctor", "Call Ambulance Service", "Call Hospital"]
        #choice = choicebox(msg, title, choices)
        choice = multchoicebox(msg, title, choices)

            #stop alarm sound
        a.close()

        # note that we convert choice to string, in case
        # the user cancelled the choice, and we got None.
        msgbox("You chose: " + str(choice), "Action is in Progress")

        msg = "Do you want to continue?"
        title = "Please Confirm"
        if ccbox(msg, title):     # show a Continue/Cancel dialog
                        pass  # user chose Continue
        else:
                        sys.exit(0)           # user chose Cancel
```

AudioFile:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

class AudioFile:
    chunk = 1024

    def __init__(self, file):
        """ Init audio stream """ 
        self.wf = wave.open(file, 'rb')
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(
            format = self.p.get_format_from_width(self.wf.getsampwidth()),
            channels = self.wf.getnchannels(),
            rate = self.wf.getframerate(),
            output = True
        )

    def play(self):
        """ Play entire file """
        data = self.wf.readframes(self.chunk)
        while data != '':
            self.stream.write(data)
            data = self.wf.readframes(self.chunk)

    def close(self):
        """ Graceful shutdown """ 
        self.stream.close()
        self.p.terminate()

# Usage example for pyaudio
#a = AudioFile("alarm.wav")
#a.play()
#a.close()
```

When i run this two codes using main file i wanted to run the alarm sound first and in background the gui should appear in the window and when i select the choices from the second window and i press ok it should stop the alarm sound but instead of that first my application play the alarm sound after it is over it start the gui. how should i play my alarm sound in the background of the gui and close it after i press the second ok button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the solution based on @ebarr sample code.

main file:

```
 predictions[0] = 1

a = AudioFile("alarm.wav")

if (predictions[0] == 1):
    while 1:
        a.start()
        sleep(0.5)
        msgbox("Critical Situation Detected!")


        msg ="Please choose an action?"
        title = "Critical Situation Detected!"
        choices = ["Ignore the Warning", "Contact Doctor", "Call Ambulance Service", "Call Hospital"]
        #choice = choicebox(msg, title, choices)
        choice = multchoicebox(msg, title, choices)

        a.stop()

        # note that we convert choice to string, in case
        # the user cancelled the choice, and we got None.
        msgbox("You chose: " + str(choice), "Action is in Progress")

        msg = "Do you want to continue?"
        title = "Please Confirm"
        if ccbox(msg, title):     # show a Continue/Cancel dialog
                        pass  # user chose Continue
        else:
                        sys.exit(0)           # user chose Cancel
```

AudioFile:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

from threading import Thread,Event
from time import sleep

class AudioFile(Thread):
    chunk = 1024

    def __init__(self, file):
        """ Init audio stream """
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.wf = wave.open(file, 'rb')
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.p.open(
            format = self.p.get_format_from_width(self.wf.getsampwidth()),
            channels = self.wf.getnchannels(),
            rate = self.wf.getframerate(),
            output = True
        )
        self._stop = Event()

def run(self):
    self._stop.clear()
    """ Play entire file """
    while not self._stop.is_set():
        data = self.wf.readframes(self.chunk)
        self.stream.write(data)

    def stop(self):
        """ Graceful shutdown """
        self._stop.set()
        self.stream.close()
        self.p.terminate()
```

Comment: Looks good. I am not familiar with `PyAudio`, but the nested while loop in the `run` method looks like it could cause you problems. I each pass of the inner while loop a tone of the alarm?

Comment: @ebarr yes, i changed it accordingly now its working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Currently, when you run the `AudioFile.play()` method you will play the entire file before the `msgbox("Critical Situation Detected!")` command is executed.

The solution to this would be to run the alarm in a thread such that control remains in the while loop in your main file.

An example of what the threaded alarm might look like (minus the details) would be:

```
from threading import Thread,Event
from time import sleep

class AudioFile(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._stop = Event()

    def run(self):
        self._stop.clear()

        # in this case we loop until the stop event is set
        while not self._stop.is_set():
            print "BEEP BEEP BEEP!"
            sleep(0.2)

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()
```

In your main code you would then replace `a.play` and `a.close` by `a.start` and `a.stop`. For example:

```
x = AudioFile()
x.start()
sleep(4)
x.stop()
```

Comment: Nowhere. The sleep statement is there purely to provide an example code that runs and that demonstrates how the threading module allows you two run two logical threads at once.